# GRUB menu doesn't show "Windows" selection in dual boot with Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have installed Ubuntu in my laptop with Windows 10 in dual boot mode. I was expecting GRUB to show me a menu with Windows/Ubuntu selection, but I see only Ubuntu there.

How I can add Windows to the GRUB menu? When Ubuntu starts I can see the Windows disk with files - so Windows is not deleted.

Disk state:

[image: partitions]